# How to get reverse in laravel one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am writing an application that I use laravel eloquent relationship

table structure

clients

---

### id
payroll_id
name

Payroll

---

### id
payroll_id
basic
hmo

Client Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AdminClient extends Model
{
    public function payroll()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payroll::class, "payroll_id", "payroll_id");
    }
}
```

Payroll Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Payroll extends Model
{
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AdminClient::class, "payroll_id", "payroll_id");
    }
}
```

I am able to do

```
dd(AdminClient::with("payroll")->get());
```

but the reverse below is not working

```
dd(Payroll::with("clients")->get());
```

I am getting a null value for the clients.

Any Solutions Thank you.

Comment: Can we see your tables structures please?

Comment: You have two problems, the first is that you wrote the relationships inside the transfer model and the second is that in the payroll table you do not need the payroll_id column at all and it is useless to create it.

Infact payroll has many clients and client blongs to a payroll.

Answer (score 0):

use this in AdminClient

```
public function payroll()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payroll::class);
    }
```

and use this in Payroll

```
public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AdminClient::class);
    }
```

or if it not work then use this in AdminClient

```
public function payroll()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payroll::class, "forign key of AdminClient");
    }
```

and use this in Payroll

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AdminClient::class, "payroll_id");
}
```

hope its work

Comment: Did not work for me